# my adsense has to be applied on a website before I be able to use admob and earn money?

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I'm going to publish my android app but?,my adsense has to be applied on a website before I be able to use admob and earn money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I use Admob for mobile apps without an active Adsense campaign on any website :)

Comment: Follow this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/